# C++ on Small-Footprint Microcontrollers

Tags: c++, oop, embedded

It seems to me people consistently shy away from, or rather vehemently oppose the use of, C++ on microcontrollers, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. If you stay away from large C++ libraries (e.g. STL) and you don't try to use complicated features like RTTI or exception handling, is there really any noticeable difference between C vs C++? Does virtual inheritance have a huge impact on complexity or footprint? I would think it'd be a little extra memory, but most of the complexity would be handled by the compiler, but then again I don't know a lot about that dark magic. I just don't understand why people are pretty adamant about using C, except maybe for the few architectures for which there aren't C++ compilers (if there are any). It seems the benefits of modularization and templates would be a no-brainer, even if you couldn't use your cin or cout.

I ask because I'm doing some research for some hobby projects I'd like to work on. Ideally, I'd like to work with C++ strictly for the capability to nicely modularize things, vs. C's "SomeClass_SomeMethod( struct object* this ... )" approach to "object orientedness". (I'd much prefer object Pascal for these projects, but alas support for that language isn't exactly stellar...) I would rather avoid moving to a much more capable microprocessor because A. for the projects I'm doing, I don't need tons of resources.. I'm not planning on writing 60 state Kalman filters or encoding 1080p video B. (the real kicker) I'd like to use processors available in DIP and QFP packages. I'd like the ability to prototype without soldering or baking anything in my toaster oven.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C++ you essentially only pay for what you use over and above what would otherwise be C compilable code, and some of the extras are cost free.

The biggest issue with some C++ compilers for small targets is the completeness of available C++ implementations or the availability of a C++ compiler at all.

EETimes/Embedded.com has run a number of articles on the subject over the years:

- [Better even at the lowest levels - Dan Saks](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026943/Better-even-at-the-lowest-levels)
- [Embedded C++ Yields Faster Smaller Code - John Carbone](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4017902/Embedded-C--Yields-Faster-Smaller-Code)
- [Why C++ is a viable alternative to C in embedded systems design - Fergus Bolger](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4008168/Why-C--is-a-viable-alternative-to-C-in-embedded-systems-design)
- [Poor reasons for rejecting C++ - Dan Saks](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4027504/Poor-reasons-for-rejecting-C-)
- [Using C++ Efficiently in Embedded Applications - Mentor Graphics/Cesar A. Quiroz](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/ESC_San_Jose_98_401_paper.pdf)
- [The Inefficiency of C++ , Fact or Fiction? - IAR Systems/Anders Lundgren](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/thegarty/iar_fact_the_inefficiency_of_C--.pdf)

The point most of these articles make is that you should not necessarily use *all* of C++ in an embedded system and they measure or explain the cost in terms of memory, speed, and determinism of various features.  What parts you use will depend on the nature of your application (whether it has real-time constraints for example), and the available resources and performance of your target platform.

Comment: +1 for the Dan Saks reference. I got to sit in on his SDWest'09 lecture "C++ on Bare Metal". Great info on using STL & Templates in embedded projects.

Comment: Saks is a hopeless preacher for C++ though, expect his articles to be very biased.

Comment: Towards using C++ before C no matter the application.

Comment: @Lundin:  It is the reader's responsibility to to come to a view, but there is no application for which C is applicable that C++ is not also usable, and C++ is a bigger tool-bag, so what's not to like?  Of course more tools gives greater opportunity to use them inappropriately, and to cut your leg off, but that's perhaps what this question (and Dan's articles) are about.

Comment: Thanks to EETimes for breaking all the links - fixed (for now).  If broken again simply search for the title/author.

Answer (score 12):

The C++ committee wrote a (free) [technical report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf) on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it varies a lot.

I wouldn't use virtual inheritance on a "small" MCU. I wouldn't even use a heap at all.

The features of C++ that seem most attractive in that space are namespaces (to share software components between programs for networked MCUs), templates (e.g., to parameterize protocols over I/O ports), and general semantic improvements like `static_cast` and less coarse integral promotion.

But, at least in my brief foray into professional embedded, a suitable C++ compiler simply didn't exist, and the crappy one that was available cost thousands a year.

GCC is the most capable, widely-available C++ compiler available for embedded platforms. However, its platform support is very uneven. If you have unlimited resources, EDG advertises that they will bring support superior to Comeau to "your" embedded platform.

Comment: TI offers C++ for MSP430 and 28xx DSPs for free.

Answer (score 3):

C++ people constantly ask "why are you using C and not C++". I would like to know why I should be using C++ and not C.

First of all, one must come to the realization that these two languages are both *ancient*, and they both have *horrible* syntax. The debate often seems to be focused around "you should use C++, because C++ is modern and C is old". In reality, the debate is about one's favourite flavour of dinosaur meat. Instead of demanding a *modern* language suitable for embedded, people preach C++, which never was anything but a weird temporary hybrid language with C compatibility, in wait for some better language to be invented.

Second, there is a myth saying that C++ is object-oriented and C is not. The buzzword object-orientation boils down to three things:

- 1) Modular design with autonomous objects, that aren't tightly coupled to anything else. This is a very important attribute of any program.
- 2) Private encapsulation of data and reduced scope of data. This is a rather important attribute of any program.
- 3) Polymorphism of classes: classes that inherit other classes and behave differently when inherited. Polymorphism is quite useful, but far less so in small embedded systems.

1) can be fully achieved in both C and C++, it is a matter of program design rather than language syntax. And this is the most important OO attribute by far! Unfortunately, there is nothing in any language standard telling you how to design your program. There is nothing in C++ that will automatically lead to a better modular design, it is all in the hands of the programmer.

2) can be achieved in both C and C++. Both languages have reduced scope of data. In C, private encapsulation is done through somewhat horrible syntax with the static keyword on file scope variables. In C++, it is done more elegantly with private/protected.

3) can be achieved in both C and C++. Both languages have *horrible* syntax for this. In C you would fiddle around with structs and function interfaces to achieve it. In C++, you can do it in less horrible ways through heritage and making functions "virtual". The C++ syntax and the needed implementation is still one big mess however, although a bit better than the C way.

Neither language will give you OO-related things in pretty, elegant ways. What C++ gains from somewhat less icky syntax, it loses when you start wading through undefined/unspecified/implementation-defined behavior.

It would seem that the whole OO argument isn't a big deal, C++ is not a huge improvement when it comes to OO. Then what else is there in C++ that I would need in my embedded system? One thing stands out: standardized inline assembler syntax. This is perhaps the biggest advantage C++ has over C, for embedded systems.

Apart from that, excpetions, STL, templates, RTTI, overator overloading, function overloading etc etc, are all more or less useless features one can live without.

Then in the end, reality comes to slap you in the face: there are extremely few, if any, embedded compilers that have managed to fully implement C++ according to the standard.

Comment: +1, I understand your arguments, I can't agree with all of them, but at all a good explanation

Comment: Age has nothing to do with it, both are *system level* languages which is what is required for most embedded development; certainly for hardware level access.  They are not of course the only such languages, they are also not the oldest such languages.

Comment: Moreover, when all you have is a bare chip, for most architectures the only language choices are typically native assembler, C or C++.  Support for other languages on a bare-metal system is usually not available, while C at least is ubiquitous, and C++ not much less so. As such these are usually your only choices for bootstrap languages.  C# for example requires .NET Micro or WinCE to run on an embedded system, and Java requires a JVM.

Comment: Age has nothing to do with it? C is 40 years old, C++ is 30 years old. They are both horrible languages. Are you still using CPUs from the early 70s too? Why aren't programming languages developed any longer? We should demand new, modern languages suitable for embedded. Java was a fiasco in this regard, and C# didn't even have the ambition to be a general-purpose language. Still, those languages are far, far better syntax-wise than C/C++. They just can't be used for realtime embedded systems, just because they require runtime platforms.

Comment: I disagree with the comment on polymorphism and small embedded devices: in embedded applications especially it is advantageous to separate application code from hardware requirements as much as possible. You can have a fairly small microcontroller capable of complicated tasks that warrant simulation and unit testing off of the target hardware. In C++ this abstraction is achieved by multiple implementations of an interface; in C this is implemented with "file level polymorphism" and ambiguous pointer passing, generally. Given the options, C++ should be a clear winner over ASM or C.

Comment: I do agree that C++ is outdated, and I could mention many other languages I would rather use, but on small devices the only options are usually ASM, C, C++, or some flavor of BASIC. Finding a C++ compiler is usually hard enough, so I'll take what I can get. :)

Comment: What language would you prefer? Support for inline assembler would seem to rule out languages with much semantic difference from the C family. Your criticisms are mostly about syntax, but we are well-equipped to handle ugly syntax. Consider English! (For a good mental exercise, take whatever criteria you have and evaluate FORTH.)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer C for these kind of systems, as it is far less messed up than C++, and with far less cases of undefined/unspecified/implementation-defined behavior. I was a big fan of C++ 10 years ago, but after using it to and fro over time, I've come to dislike it more and more. To me, C++ is "lets see if we can obfuscate this more, for obfuscation's sake, with the fanatic, irrational believe that this must be great program design". C ain't pretty either, but you can focus more on actual programming than on language oddities when using it.

Answer (score 2):

> is there really any noticeable difference between C vs C++?

In my experience there is a big difference in the usage of RAM.

For example: I am currently working on C++ for an ARM uC with 512KB FALSH and 64KB of RAM.
RAM usage should be less than 30kB but is twice that because every const ends up in RAM.
That is because it is nearly impossible (at least with GCC and ARM targets) to convince the compiler to leave const class members in FLASH.  The only way to achive this is by using constructor-less classes, declaring all const members public and using aggregate initializer lists.

To make things worse, C++ does not allow members to be named in the initializer list like you can do in plain C:

```
struct St {  int b;  int a[3];  };

static const struct St st_array[2] =
{
    [1] = { .a = {1,2,3,},  .b = 10, }, // deliberately disordered to
    [0] = { .b = 8,  .a = { 4,5,6,}, }, // illustate the value of names.
};
```

All C-compilers will put these constants into the "constant data" segment (in FLASH).

In C++ you would have to do this:

```
class ClassA  // cannot have constructor or destructor
{
public:  // const data cannot be private for aggregate initialization
    const int b;
    const int a[3];
private:
    int priv_fn(int i);
public:
    int pub_fn();
};

static ClassA classA_array[2] = 
{   
    { 3, { 8, 9,10,}, },  // aggregate initialization 
    { 4, { 9,10,11,}, },  // better get the order right!!!
};
```

Depending on your compiler, even this may not guarantee that the constants stay in FLASH.

And yes I know, with C++0x you can use initializer lists with the constructor and that is what I am doing, but the moment you have a constructor which gets called at runtime, all initializations become dynamic.

The [technical report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf) (thanks MSalters) confirms this:

> 7.1.2 Constructors and ROMable Objects
> In general, const objects of classes with constructors must be dynamically initialized.
> However, in some cases compile-time initialization could be performed if static analysis ...

The bottom line is that such static analysis is not done by any compiler I have available and if I have to limit myself to constructor-less classes with public consts and without initializer naming then I might as well write in plain (and object-oriented) C.

Answer (score 1):

For "small footprint" where I would be concerned is code bloat. If your code needs to reside in a small piece of hardware, an instance of the template class

```
 std::vector<int>
```

has its own set of instructions, seperate from

```
 std::vector<double>
```

So every time you create a new kind of vector, the compiler effectively copy-pastes the code to create the new class, with its own set of functions, duplicating every instruction. If you have constraints on the amount of memory to store instructions, this could become problematic very fast. Its become problematic for people on non Embedded systems.

In terms of runtime performance, though, I think you don't have much [to worry about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618957/is-c-faster-than-c). In some cases, such as sorting, [C++ outperforms C](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/rants/c++-vs-c/).

Comment: Of course, modern C++ linkers check at binary level for duplicate functions, and STL implementors know how to use that. As a result, `std::vector<int>::clear()` may be folded with `std::vector<double>::clear()` because both release all memory, calling no destructors.

Comment: @MSalters, true but you can't eliminate all duplication, and some of these custom microcontrollers you have to use commercial compilers of varying levels of quality.

Comment: You can't eliminate all duplication in hand-rolled collections either. And they suffer equally from bad compilers .

Comment: @MSalters, maybe vector is a bad example then. Something more like boost::assign::list_of where you could get the same functionality without code duplication