# Micro-Controllers programming

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, microcontroller, pic

I'm having this robotic arm project along with some engineers we haven't settled for the Micro Controller of choice yet but currently a PIC is being tested. I was wondering if there were Micros that support C++ ?

Background:
I'm a (Java) software developer, beginner in Embedded systems, currently programming using Mikro Elektronika IDE and C language.

Comment: When you decide on a micro controller be sure to read this Q&A on Microcontroller OOP with C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710942/c-on-small-footprint-microcontrollers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AVR, MSP-430, Blackfin, almost anything 32 bit (ARM, AVR32, Renasis RX family).

If you are starting from nothing, an ARM is probably the best way to go.  Atmel, NXP, TI and others have single chip ARM microcontrollers with inexpensive development kits.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for C++, but I just got a netduino that runs C# (very similar in syntax and concept to Java) and I'm loving it.

The whole dev board (which in many aspects is compatible with readily available arduino shields) costs less than 40 bucks.

Comment: An arduino board (and derivatives such as this) will also run C++ code; the compiler is a GCC derivative.

Comment: I know. I only mentioned netduino because user797044 had already mentioned ARMs and other platforms that accept C++. The OP mentioned Java, so I just wanted to point to a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Going metal with C++ is not optimal for a number of reasons, simply because you are not running on top of an operating system and, to name one, dynamic memory allocation simply doesn't exists. No new no malloc. I don't mean you CAN'T go C++, but I would refrain.

I've used Mikroe C for PICs, it's ok but I'd go with MPLAB, just a matter of personal taste.

If you wanna go ARM, go GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to hexa's answer that for ARM llvm is also a good compiler (I use binutils to assemble and link).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the mbed plattform? It's an open source arduino-like board which I consider to be more powerful. It is programmed in C/C++ and the good part is that there are literally thousands of APIs you can use in your project.

Hope this helps

https://mbed.org/