# C++ compiled C code vs Pure C in embedded programming?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I have read C vs C++ stuffs and why C is preferred over C++ but what will be the impact of writing C code compiled with a C++ compiler and using in embedded programs, There might be some difference in standard definitions like null pointer etc.

To make it clearer, if I write a embedded.cpp with just c codes and compile with a c++ compiler, will the resulting code be as efficient as the embedded.c code. My guess is C compilers has been highly optimized and produce optimized code. Is that all the reason ?

Comment: Basically, compilers first **translate code to their intermediate language** and next to the machine code, so that in, for example GCC, there are the same optimizations available for C and C++. Why use the C++ compiler for C code?

Comment: yes there is no point to use C++ compiler for a C code.But I just wanted to know will gcc and g++ on exactly the same code produce the same efficient code that can be used in an environment like embedded programming.

Comment: There's no reason to expect something to be more efficient just because you wrote it in C.  Perhaps less in fact since what C++ will do for must be done by hand in C and thus there's more room to screw up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any comparison only makes sense when you are looking at particular compilers.  Some leading compilers use the exact same back end for both C++ and C, and library choice (that impacts disk footprint, memory footprint, startup time and almost everything else) is determined quite freely and in a much more granular way than just C vs. C++, supposing you really care.

So in that case the answer would be, no, the file extension does not matter.  But calling a C program C is very good to make your decision to limit the product to C to be understood within your team.

Note that a lot of the argument against C++ in embedded development comes from an era a decade or more ago when C++ compilers struggled to implement the language correctly, and sometimes at the expense of predictable performance or runtime size.  All today's practical language wars for embedded devepment that are fought close to me tend to be between C++ and C# and C is rarely even remembered.

Comment: "...C is rarely even remembered" - and for good reason ;)

Comment: I've see some truly terrible C code in products and C is a simple language. C++ programmers are not likely, on average, to be any smarter or better trained than C programmers, and C++ is way more complicated than C. My bet is that there is a fair bit of C++ code that is like terrible C code, squared. Only a guess though :-)

Comment: What do you consider an embedded system to be? A laptop? A smart phone? It seems that you have only seen some strange little niche of the whole embedded market. If we look at real embedded systems that aren't just another flavour of a PC: automotive/industrial/medtech/aerospace etc etc, approximately 90% of the embedded market is C. The other 10% are mainly assembler, C++ and ADA, where assembler is likely still the largest of those three. C# and Java are next to non-existent in embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin - I agree that the device type matters a lot.  My personal experience is mostly from automotive and retail, all devices I ever coded for well capable of running VxWorks, Linux, WinCE, XPe, or POSReady (except for phones).  *If* you can afford an OS, you can probably well afford C++ these days, or pick and choose C++ features whose cost you understand well.  I was basically referring to a particular thread of long gone thinking, based on the once correct idea that using any of C++ necessarily makes your software more resource hungry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B

Comment: @WilliamMorris - The question isn't where you can fail, but where you can succeed.  There's great and efficient C code and great and efficient C++ code.  Our own (NCR) embedded C++ code often looks more like "C with Classes" than like C++11.  But we still reap some considerable benefits of safer type checking, encapsulation, libraries, exception handling etc.

Comment: EC++ or other subsets of C++ are likely going to be very similar to C. Modern embedded C++ development uses a safe subset, such as [MISRA-C++](http://www.misra-cpp.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/171/Default.aspx). A safe subset of the language, be it C or C++, is a _must_ for the kind of embedded systems I mentioned earlier. ->

Comment: That being said, the benefit of using restricted C++ vs restricted C is less ugly code. Both C and C++ supports encapsulation, but it is harder and uglier in C, where you would use opaque types and static file scope variables. Libraries are easier to find for C than for C++, since there are far more protocol stacks, RTOS, drivers etc written for C. Professionals do _not_ rely solely on the type checking on the C/C++ compiler (C == unsafe, C++ == slightly unsafe), but use external static analyser tools. Exception handling is typically either banned or heavily restricted in embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin - I agree with you on all points in the context of automotive except for libraries.  By library availability I meant primarily general purpose constructs like containers or strings; however there is not a single C library that cannot be safely called from C++ given adequate coding style guidelines.  Misra C is basically a set of coding style guidelines, too.  (Back to the topic: Misra C does not prohibit using a .cpp extension for C source files; but that does not make the practice asked about here any safer).

Comment: @Lundin: I agree that C# is not prevalent beyond Windows Embedded/WinCE or .Net Micro all of which are a tiny proportion of embedded systems, but I equally query your stats. Here are [some 2011 figures](http://blog.vdcresearch.com/embedded_sw/2011/06/2011-embedded-engineer-survey-results-programming-languages-used-to-develop-software.html).  Of course all respondents are self selecting, and the question was about languages in use rather then volume of code in any particular language.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I actually never mentioned MISRA-C, but MISRA-C++ released in 2008. Since I never use C++ for embedded, I have no idea what the latter contains, I'm guessing it is something similar to EC++, just more detailed.

Comment: @Lundin - Apologies.  EC++ was just a short lived regional fad, basically an attempted language.  I'm no longer in automotive to which MISRA-anything is more or less confined, so I can't help you regarding MISRA-C++ content or popularity.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your code with a c++ compiler, a c++ runtime is expected from the environment, including stack unwinding, handling of ctor/dtor entries, etc, which may not exist.

C requires a simpler runtime environment (crt0 and a clean initial state) and should be ready in almost all platforms.

The decision only matters if you're working on (or developing) a platform that has limited c++ support from the OS, libstdc++, or the toolchain.

By the way, I believe modern C and C++ compilers can produce equally optimized code in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile code with a C++ compiler, then that code is by definition C++ code not C, even if it is also valid C code.

Some valid C code is not valid C++ code, especially true of C99 specific features, and some code that is valid in both may have slightly different semantics - the meaning of `const` for example.  However in most cases this will make little or no difference to the generated code or its performance.

You would typically see no realistically measurable performance difference between C and C++ compilation of the same code using the same compiler suite.  C++ has slightly different run-time start-up whereby it must call constructors for global static objects before main(); however, if your C++ code is also valid C, there will be no constructors, so no overhead.

C++ has stricter type agreement requirements, and stronger error checking - it is somewhat less permissive about what is valid code; generally if your C code compiles as C++ without errors or warnings, then it is probably better/cleaner code.  There are some exceptions, for example in C one is generally [discouraged from explicitly casting the return from `malloc()`](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html), but in C++ one has no choice, and because implicit function declarations are not required the argument for not doing so in C does not hold. So in this case to make your C code valid C++ you would have to write it in a way that while valid in C, some might consider bad practice.  Personally if you suppress or ignore your C compiler's warnings about missing prototypes, then you probably get what you deserve in any case, so I would argue writing your C code for C++ compatibility in any case.

With respect to optimisation, when the same compiler suite is used, the optimisations in the C compiler are likely identical to those in the C++ compiler, except perhaps in the few cases where the precise semantics differ.

Beyond that, to use C++ code that is valid C is to miss many of the benefits of C++.  Rather a lot of C++ specific features are available to you at little or no runtime cost.  Some features on the other hand are relatively expensive - be sure you know which are viable on your particular target and application before using them.  I have listed some resources that may help with that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710942/c-on-small-footprint-microcontrollers/5721471#5721471).

Answer (score 0):

C++ runtime has heavy start up cost and termination cost. 
Unless you have to use C++ features, you should always build with C instead of C++.

Also, if your app is just C code, you also want to decorate every function prototype you use with throw(), or the C++ compiler assumes every function you call can throw and generate less than optimal code.

Comment: Not so.  I have been using C++ on bare-metal embedded systems for years, and have had to implement the runtime start-up on a number of occasions.  The only difference is that C++ calls constructors for global static objects *before* entering main().  That is presumably initialisation that would have to take case in any case one way or another; it is just a matter of when it occurs.  If you have no such objects, there is no overhead.

Comment: for example, cout, cin, cerr are always constructed whether you use it or not.

Comment: I beg to differ; they are provided by the library, not built-in, if the C++ library is not linked (and many embedded systems do not use the C++ library), the objects will not be instantiated.  Certainly if the code is *only* valid C, there would be no need to link iostreams.

Comment: I don't know of a C++ compiler that does not generate stuff that allows you not to link with the C++ library. As long as you link with the C++ library, you run a lot of code that might have nothing to do with your application.

Comment: All compilers will allow you that level of control one way or another. In GNU use --nostdlib for example, then explicitly link libc if you need the C library. In many bare-metal targeted embedded compilers you must explicitly link the standard libraries in any case.  I am currently using ARM RealView, and it is clear from the map file that there are no C++ library code or objects.  Be clear we are talking about embedded systems here; compilers for targets with a full OS will typically link default libraries and have closed start-up code.