# Why aren't object oriented languages popular in the embedded world?

Tags: oop, embedded

I'm a firmware developper and I usually develop firmware in C or Assembly. However, I came across a project completely implemented in C++ in our embedded library. Now I know object oriented languages can be used on a hardware level, but I would like to know why they aren't that popular when developing embedded systems.

Comment: Java is embedded all over the place.

Comment: memory /processing power limitations are often the reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710942/c-on-small-footprint-microcontrollers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real reason: because of conceptual complexity. C and assembly provide an a simple mental model to track what is going on in the system. Object oriented programs require a more complex model that makes it harder to reason about what is going on.

Embedded systems tend to be environments that call for very tight control about what is going on in the system versus the more open ended server and PC environment. This requires both simple and transparent programming constructs. Both C and assembly provide a high level of visibility on what is really going on in the system at the lowest hardware level.

Object oriented languages in general and C++ in particular, abstract away many of the details of what is going on in the system when code is executed, thus making it much harder to reason about the inner working of the system.

Here is an example to explain what I mean. Consider the following code snippet:

```
i++;
```

Seeing this in a C program gives us a mostly accurate idea about what this does and an order of magnitude about how many CPU cycles are used, how many registers are involved and so on.

Now what does the same line will do in a C++ program? well, it depends. Depends on what type i is and how has the ++ operator been overloaded. See what I mean?

None of these comes to say that C++ or object oriented is bad. It is not. It does require a much more complex mental model if one is interested about the minute details about what is really going in the system, as many embedded developers feel they need.

Comment: "The real reason: because of conceptual complexity." - then why is it possible to program MCUs or other embedded devices in C++? (Hint: this is *not* the real reason. Maybe compiling C++ code is harder than assembling assembly or compiling C, but the end result looks the same.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think you understood my response. Of course that it is possible to program embedded system with C++. My point was that embedded system programmer prefer not to use C++ because it requires they maintain a more complex *mental* model of what is going on. This has nothing to do with the compiler you use. It has everything to do with the "compiler" in the programmers head.

Comment: I see. Yes, that's also true.

Answer (score 3):

From technical point of view, embedded systems have limited resources. Object oriented languages tend to create much bigger binaries than pure procedural ones, thus many would choose something that's as light as possible. For instance, I work for a smartcard company and my team is the one handling extremely low cost cards, with RAM ranging only from 1.5 - 1.75 KB and EEPROM from 96 - 136 KB. For this kind of embedded environment, most object oriented languages (especially the heavy ones such as Java) won't fit. We don't even use ANY standard C library, everything is written from scratch for size. C++ might fit, with proper coding technique and use of compiler options that doesn't generate rtti, minimize vmt, use only stack based objects, etc. but it's just my guess.

Answer (score 2):

"OO languages" is too broad. There are lots of object-oriented languages with radically different characteristics. **"It can be done in C++" doesn't imply "it can be done in any OO language".** Good luck for writing a Python program for a less powerful AVR MCU for example. The device has 2kB of RAM and 32kB of Flash memory, the Python interpreter itself doesn't even fit into them.

---

C++ is a language with high-level **and** low-level parts **at the same time.** It's object-oriented, but at the end, your nice OO code will be compiled down to raw machine code, just as if you wrote it in C or assembly directly. Some other object-oriented languages, which are considered "higher-level" (or high-level-only, rather), can't do the same thing. It's all about the implementation of a particular language, really.

Comment: You can write OO code in assembly.  Assembly is certainly used in embedded.

Comment: @dwelch And then? I didn't assert that you can't write OO code in assembly. I said that certain OO languages require more capabilities than embedded systems have.

Comment: OO is too broad, the poster assumes that OO doesnt work in embedded which is simply not true, nor is C++ not used in embedded, etc.  The whole question is based on a lack of knowledge.  Your answer was the best of the ones here with respect to exposing that.

Comment: Probably the most valid point here is that a system with a tiny amount of RAM is unsuited to an approach which makes heavy usage of runtime allocation of data structures (ie, objects)

Comment: @dwelch Ah, so you were agreeing? In this case, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes I was agreeing...

Comment: @dwelch I'm sorry but since when is not popular = never used / doesn't work? I already mentioned, I know and have seen embedded C++ codes...

Comment: @hhachem C++ is often used in embedded, not sure why you think it isnt.  Like any language that is used (java, forth, basic, etc) you need to manage the lack of an operating system if we are talking bare metal (would have to assume that from your question) from a language and tools perspective.  And also manage the high level language bloat, no matter what high level language it is C, C++, etc.  C+asm makes these things easier to manage if for no other reason than momentum.  Been doing it that way for so long hard to break something else in as the primary solution.

Answer (score 2):

One addition to what all others said:

We don't write much C++ embedded code because the customer demands it. In my field code may need to get a certification and certification guidelines only exist for C, not C++.

Therefore the project has to be implemented in C even if C++ would lead to a better product.

Answer (score 0):

Because many developers "think" that C++ is not suitable for embedded environment at all because of code size and performance! and this is not true in most cases !

I strongly recommend to read [those slides](http://software-integrity.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TalkSlides.pdf) which is talking about C++ usage for embedded and talking about C++ myths like:

The "Bloat" Myth !

The "Poor Performance" Myth !

Many compiler vendors for embedded targets provide C++ compilers like Keil , IAR , CodeRed also processor manufactures provide their toolchain with C++ compilers e.g. Texas Instruments, Freescale,...

Generally the developer need to consider c++ while starting a new project and determine to use it or not based on project needs and what OOP/C++ could provide to get the job done on time on cost!