# Why does using C++ iterators increase code size drastically compared to at() or indexing?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, iterator, embedded

I have been looking at using the newer C++ language features such as iterators on embedded systems (16KB of SRAM and 64 KB of flash, Cortex M4) and hit a surprising roadblock. Why on earth are iterators so monstrously large? I was under the impression they are basically some pointer arithmetic or indexing. Is the STL pulling in some unexpected code?

These are using Kinetis Design Studio on windows with the gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9 toolchain from [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download) using the following flags.

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fsingle-precision-constant -flto  -g3 -I"../Sources" -I"../Includes" -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"Sources/System.d" -MT"Sources/System.o" -c -o "Sources/System.o" "../Sources/System.cpp"
```

ITM_SendChar just takes a single char and puts it in a register.

```
std::string input = "Oh hai there! :D\n";

#ifdef char_array
    // .text              7352
    // .data               376
    // .bss                236
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
            ITM_SendChar(input[i]);
#endif

#ifdef char_at
    // .text              7392
    // .data               376
    // .bss                236
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        ITM_SendChar(input.at(i));
#endif

#ifdef char_itterator
    // .text             39744        
    // .data               384   
    // .bss                252   
    for(char some_char : input)
        ITM_SendChar(some_char);
#endif

#ifdef char_itterator_auto
    // .text             39744        
    // .data               384   
    // .bss                252   
    for(auto some_char : input)
        ITM_SendChar(some_char);
#endif

#ifdef char_itterator_auto_no_copy
    // .text             39744        
    // .data               384   
    // .bss                252   
    for(auto& some_char : input)
        ITM_SendChar(some_char);
#endif
```

Comment: Are you compiling in some debug configuration? I do not know your build environment, but, e.g., in Visual C++'s debug config all sorts of checking are done.

Comment: First off you should compare apples to apples and not be making copies in the ranged based for loop.  What happens if you use `auto& some_char : input`?

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver for the suggestion, but no change. I added the results to my question. And JohnB there is the -g3 flag for debugging but removing it makes no difference. KDS as far as I am aware does not include anything extra when debugging.

Comment: You have to ask yourself perhaps whether using the STL at all on such a resource constrained environment is appropriate (it's mostly not!).  On your platform it is probably appropriate to restrict yourself to a subset that avoids templates and "hidden" dynamic memory allocation - which means no STL and no `std::string`.  The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710942/c-on-small-footprint-microcontrollers/5721471 may be useful with respect to using C++ in small targets.

Comment: @Clifford: Templates are a pure compiler thing. At runtime, there's no distinction between `f<int>()` and `f_int()`,

Comment: Shouldn't there be some linker flag to remove unused sections? That's the whole reason to use `-ffunction-sections` isn't it?

Comment: @MSalters : True, but `f<int>()` and `f<char>()` produce *different* code, where you might otherwise have used `static_cast<char>(f_int())`.  I have worked on projects where avoidable template instantiations have caused code bloat - it is hard to manage in large development teams.  However that was not really my biggest concern;  instantiating templates of your own code can be carefully controlled - I was referring rather to the use of the STL over which you have far less control, and can have a huge impact on code size, heap usage, and determinism.

Comment: @Clifford: Not a convincing comparison, is it? `static_cast<char>(f<int>())`.  As for large development teams, how many developers do you expect for a target that has 16 kB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (or two) C++ standards ago it was legal for iterators to be implemented with pointers.  (You can google "removed weasel wording" in the standard to find out more about this.)  Newer standards require more from iterators, for example that if you have two corresponding iterators in two containers of the same type, then swapping those two containers also requires swapping those two iterators (see N4527 23.2.1 footnote 9 to read it for yourself, if you like).  All of this means that indexing into a container with indexes instead of iterators can certainly be more efficient.  It's just that that isn't supported for all standard container types...  And that's also why using iterators increases code size.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between the [] operator and .at() is that .at() does bounds checking, and will throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.

It seems likely that the standard library implementation you're using is linking in extra code for something when using an iterator. The only way to find the cause is to examine the linker map file for both versions, and look closely at source code for the functions you're using, and maybe the generated assembly too.

In general, if you need your code to be very small you want to avoid using any of the standard library, because the functions in there can pull in lots of code and data with them. Even the code that parses the command line into the format that main() expects can be quite big.

For comparison, try this:

```
const char *input = "Oh hai there! :D\n";

while (*input)
        ITM_SendChar(*input++);
```

Comment: What you just showed is also totally adequate in terms of code size, thanks. I was just hoping to get in on the iterator magic for embedded since it both looked like it can be very useful and have minimal code size impact due to my understanding of how iterators work, but sadly it seems that's a no go.

I will look into the linker map file later to see if I can find out what's up and if there are any workarounds so I can still use iterators without having all my flash go the way of the dodo.

Comment: @hak8or - *"What you just showed is also totally adequate in terms of code size..."* - you often use `CXXFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and `LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections` to reduce code size. But that's a different problem/question than *"Why does using C++ iterators increse code size drastically compared to at() or indexing?"* and *"Why on earth are iterators so monstrously large?"*